# DotNetNuke User control not working .it shows data from .resource file in Portal>0>cache>pages.Not able to debug User control

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am new in Dotnetnuke and not able to debug my website with visual studio .It showing data from .resource file not from USer control

Comment: You will want to provide more information about how you have DNN running, what you are trying to debug, what version of Visual Studio you are trying to use, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a series of DNN tutorials that I started on recently (I wrote a majority of the old ones on dotnetnuke.com) that talk through the process of setting up your development environment, and then using the Visual Studio Templates that I have created/released (open source).

I would encourage anyone trying to really do any development with DotNetNuke to check those out. http://www.christoc.com/tutorials